# Cannot change python interpreter

Tags: python, pycharm, anaconda

I imported a python project from github into pycharm. I developed this project in windows but now i am using mac.

I changed the project interpreter in the settings but when running it says: "error running the project" and the error message says that it points to the python interpreter of my old windows directory.

I have already tried to delete my /user/USR_NAME/Library/Caches but it didn't help. I also changed the project interpreter but it didn't help

I am using python2.7 with anaconda

Is there any project properties file with the old settings?

Answer (score 3):

I found the solution. There is a file under the project directory: .idea/workspace.xml which contains the older setting. Deleting this file caused pycharm to recreate it with the new settings.

Comment: This is the most useful answer I've ever seen. No DevOps guy in my company could trace this PyCharm clumsiness. I didn't delete the xml. I rather changed the file manually. It worked. Thanks!